# Python Regex strange behavior with accented characters

Tags: python, regex

I was experimenting with some Python (2.7.3) regex and I came across this behavior which I did not expect. In this block of code here, the following will return `False` when checking against the "ß" character as well as other accented characters like "Å", "Í", etc.

In addition to returning `False` for the "ø" character, it will also return `False` with other accented characters such as "å", "Å", "ç", "Ç", "Â", etc.

Case and point, I'm not sure where the problem stems from when dealing with accented characters versus other characters like "¥", which it has no problem with. They all have different unicode/utf-8 values (which is what my encoding is set to), so I'm not sure where the difference lies.

```
def regex_check(name)
    pattern = '[^ß]'
    if re.match(pattern, str(name), re.IGNORECASE):
        return True
    else:
        return False

print regex_check("ø")
```

Am I missing something obvious? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normal strings are bytes in Python 2, you should use the `u'...'` prefix to treat them as unicode strings.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
def regex_check(name):
    pattern = u'[^ß]'    #use u'...' here  
    if re.match(pattern, name , re.IGNORECASE):
        return True
    else:
        return False

print regex_check(u"ø")  #use u'...' here
```

**output:**

```
True
```

Comment: The re.UNICODE flag shouldn't have any effect here. It should return True regardless.

Comment: @nhahtdh You're right, properly file encoding and using u'...' will handle everything.

Comment: I think you should explain that in your answer (rather than just code).

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Shouldn't it give a decoding error instead of failed regex if file encoding is absent or file encoding is ascii? I think the issue is just that the string should be declared as unicode.

Comment: @Abhijit OP has already set their encoding to `utf-8`, yes the problem was `u'..'` thing only.