# Find all accented words/characters with Python regex?

Tags: python, regex

I've seen a lot of different posts for handling accented characters, but none that specifically find accented characters in a corpus of text. I'm trying to identify words in the text like `nǚ`, but the code should not include non-Latin-alphabet results. Ex: 女 should not be selected. The string I'm using for testing is:

```
"nǚ – woman; girl; daughter; female. A pictogram of a woman with her arms stretched. In old versions she was seated on her knees.  It is a radical that forms part tón of characters related to women and their qualities. 女儿   nǚ'ér – daughter (woman + child) ǚa"
```

A working regex should select:

- nǚ
- nǚ'ér
- ǚa
- tón

Note:
There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50847976/python-regex-to-find-accented-words), but the problem is different. This person is just having trouble using regex with accents.

Comment: What is this double accent `ǚ` ? I got regex for the other but not for that one

Comment: It's an unusual Chinese sound. It has the same pronunciation as the German umlaut, but the little carrot deal is indicating that it's a third tone. I picked it on purpose because it's one of the weirder ones I have to identify.

Comment: seem to be referenciwng unicode. have idea what latin means for unicode, yes ?

Comment: can accent chars be a join of 2 chars ? visually how know from 1 or 2, ? dont, yes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match the accented letter, from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690499/concrete-javascript-regex-for-accented-characters-diacritics) you can use

- `[\u00C0-\u017F]`
- `[À-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]`

- `ǚ` is not included in but you can extend unicode range to its value : `[\u00C0-\u01DA]`
- `'` is not an accent you have to add it manually

Giving final **`\w*[\u00C0-\u01DA']\w*`** and  [**`Code Demo`**](https://repl.it/repls/IdenticalAggravatingCygwin)

Comment: Dude, I have no idea why someone downvoted you - you're a champion. I had some ideas, but that is soooooo much better than what I came up with. You just saved me a huge amount of time. I'd hug you if we were in person.

Comment: @GrantCurell - social distancing, remember? :P

Comment: @MattDMo No virus can halt my borderline inappropriate friendliness.

Answer (score 0):

A generic solution for Cyrillic, Arabic, etc. would be

```
[x for x in re.findall(r"\b[^\W\d_]+(?:['’][^\W\d_]+)*\b", s) 
    if re.search(r'[A-Za-z]',x) and re.search(r'(?![a-zA-Z])[^\W\d_]',x)]
```

- `re.findall(r"\b[^\W\d_]+(?:['’][^\W\d_]+)*\b"`  - finds all words that may contain apostrophes
- `if re.search(r'[A-Za-z]',x)` - make sure there is a letter from ASCII range
- `re.search(r'(?![a-zA-Z])[^\W\d_]',x)` - also, make sure there is a letter outside of ASCII range.